# Limit of $a_n := \frac{5^n}{2^{n^2}}$

Tags: calculus

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_n := \frac{5^n}{2^{n^2}}$.
1. Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded below by $0$.
We note that $a_n > 0$ for $n\geq 0$. Thus, the sequence is bounded from below.
2. Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing by showing that $a_{n+1}-a_n < 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
We look to $a_n = \frac{5^n}{2^{n^2}}$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{5^{n+1}}{2^{(n+1)^2}}$. For $n\geq 1$ we see that $a_n > a_{n+1}$. Therefore, we have a strictly decreasing sequence.
3. Deduce that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges and calculate its limit.
Since we have a (monotonically) decreasing sequence which is bounded below, by the monotone convergence theorem this sequence converges. How do we find the limit? Is it the squeeze theorem? Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know a limit $L$ exists, then find a recurrence relation, like 
$$a_{n+1} = \frac52\frac{1}{2^{2n}}a_n$$
And take the limit as $n\to\infty$:
$$L = \frac{5}{2}\cdot0\cdot L$$
which implies that limit $L$ must equal $0$.

Comment: Great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for  $ n\ge 3$, we have $$2^{n^2} >6^n$$

Therefore  $$\frac{5^n}{2^{n^2}}<(5/6)^n \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac 52\times 4^{-n}\to 0$ so if $a_n\to \ell$ and $|\ell|>0$

Then $\frac{\ell}{\ell}=0$ by limit identification, this is a contradiction, so $\ell=0$

Alternately for $n\ge 1,\quad\frac 52\times 4^{-n}\le \frac 58<1$

Thus $0\le a_n\le\left(\frac 58\right)^{n-1}a_1\to 0$

*Note: You should have seen this from question 2. $a_{n+1}-a_n<0$ is not easy to study, but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ is, both giving you the decreasing behaviour. Consequently you get a geometric sequence with a reason lower than $1$, which is forced to converge to $0$. You missed this point.*

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: The are many ways to show this but we will use induction. Well $a_1 = \frac{5}{2} > 0$. Now suppose that $a_n > 0$ for some $n$. Then
\begin{equation*}
a_{n+1} = \frac{5^{n+1}}{2^{(n+1)^2}} = \frac{5^{n+1}}{2^{n^2+2n+1}} = \frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}\cdot \frac{5^n}{2^{n^2}} = \frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}\cdot a_n.
\end{equation*}
Since $a_n > 0$ and $\frac{5}{2^{2n+1}} > 0$, we see that $a_{n+1} > 0$. Hence, $a_n > 0$ as required.
For the second question: We have
\begin{equation*}
a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}\cdot a_n-a_n = \left(\frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}-1\right)a_n.
\end{equation*}
Now $a_n > 0$ so
\begin{equation*}
a_{n+1}-a_n < 0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}-1 < 0 \Longleftrightarrow 5 < 2^{2n+1},
\end{equation*}
which is easy to prove by induction: For $n = 1$, $2^{2\times 1+1} = 2^3 = 8 > 5$. Now if $2^{2n+1} > 5$, then
\begin{equation*}
2^{2(n+1)+1} = 2^{2n+3} = 2^2\cdot 2^{2n+1} = 4\cdot 2^{2n+1} > 4\times 5 = 20 > 5.
\end{equation*}
Thus, the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing as required.
For the final question: Since we have a (monotonically) decreasing sequence which is bounded below, by the monotone convergence theorem $(a_n)$ converges, say to $\ell$. Then because $a_{n+1} = \frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}\cdot a_n$ we get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\ell = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{5}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\cdot \ell = 0\cdot \ell = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
because $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{2n+1} = \infty$.